# How to compute the classic differential of a section

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a section $s:M\to E$ of a vector bundle, I'm trying to compute its differential, $Ts:TM\to TE$ in a local trivialization. To do this, I can write 
$$s=f^ie_i$$
For some local frame $(e_i)$ of $E$, and smooth functions $f^i$. Then I would like to write 
$$Ts=T(f^ie_i)=\sum_{i=1}^nf^iTe_i$$
and proceed in the computation etc...

However, this would be incorrect, since the classic differential does not satisfy the properties that a differential operator should satisfy, namely, linearity, and the Leibniz rule. To see what I mean, note

- Letting $D$ be the ordinary Jacobian operator,

  - $D(\mathbf f+\mathbf g)=D\mathbf f+D\mathbf g$
  - $D(\alpha\mathbf g)=\mathbf gD\alpha+\alpha D\mathbf g$,

  for $\mathbf f,\mathbf g$ as vector valued functions, and $\alpha$ a scalar valued function.
- However,

  - $[T(f+g)(X)](h)=X(h\circ (f+g))\neq X(h\circ f)+X(h\circ g)$, unless $h$ is linear, which it is not in general.
  - The leibniz rule breaks down, in startling fashion.

However, I hear all the time the claim that the pushforward is modeled off of the Jacobian. This is frustrating, and I now need a way out of this mess. How can I successfully compute a differential in a local trivialization?

Comment: The pushforward of what?

Comment: The pushforward as an operator - e.g. if I use functorial notation, I am wondering why $T(f+g)\neq Tf+Tg$, etc...

Comment: The pushforward as as an operator of what?

Comment: As an operator on the space of sections of a vector bundle. i.e. for $f:M\to E$, $Tf:TM\to TE$.

Comment: What do you mean by the pushforward of a section of a vector bundle?

Comment: The pushforward of a section $f$ of a vector bundle is a map $Tf$ from the tangent bundle of the base manifold to the tangent bundle of the vector bundle, satisfying $$Tf(X)=X(\_\circ f)$$ where $X$ is a tangent vector.

Comment: "Pushforward" seems like a really strange term for this construction. Isn't it just the differential of $f$?

Comment: Sure. I'm just using Lee's notation (Introduction to Smooth manifolds, 1st ed)